# How to create a canvas element in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, canvas

I have this part of code in Node.JS:

```
const canvas = createCanvas(cnn_size, cnn_size)
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
pairs.forEach(pair => {
    if (value.keypoints[pair[0]].score > kp_score &&
        value.keypoints[pair[1]].score > kp_score) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'green'
        ctx.lineWidth = 2

        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.moveTo(value.keypoints[pair[0]].position.x, value.keypoints[pair[0]].position.y)
        ctx.lineTo(value.keypoints[pair[1]].position.x, value.keypoints[pair[1]].position.y)
        ctx.stroke()
    }
})
const buffer = Buffer.from(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data)
let tensor = tf.tensor(buffer, [1, canvas.width, canvas.height, 4])
tensor = tensor.slice([0, 0, 0, 0], [1, canvas.width, canvas.height, 3])
return tensor
```

There is no `createCanvas` in React Native's Canvas so I don't know how to achieve the same result of the above code in React Native. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Come up with my own implementation of drawing line on an UInt8Array():

```
function drawLine(u, v, array) {
    let a = v.y - u.y;
    let b = u.x - v.x;
    let c = a * u.x + b * u.y;
    for (let i = Math.min(u.x, v.x) ; i <= Math.max(u.x, v.x); ++i) {
        let j = Math.floor((c - a * i) / b);
        array[j * cnn_size * 3 + 3 * i + 1] = 255;
    }
    for (let j = Math.min(u.y, v.y) ; j <= Math.max(u.y, v.y); ++j) {
        let i = Math.floor((c - b * j) / a);
        array[j * cnn_size * 3 + 3 * i + 1] = 255;
    }
}

async function makeTensorFromKeypoints(value) {
    let uint8 = new Uint8Array(cnn_size * cnn_size * 3);
    pairs.forEach(pair => {
        if (value.keypoints[pair[0]].score > kp_score &&
            value.keypoints[pair[1]].score > kp_score) {
            drawLine(value.keypoints[pair[0]], value.keypoints[pair[1]], uint8);
        }
    })
    let tensor = tf.tensor(uint8, [1, cnn_size, cnn_size, 3]); //dit me may thg lz stackoverflow bo may hoi ca chuc cau deo thg nao tra loi dc phe pham vai ca lon
    return tensor;
}
```